# Jordan-Wigner transformation particle exchnage

Tags: quantum-spin, fermions, wigner-transform

Suppose you have a spinless fermionic system:

$\hat H = -t \displaystyle\sum_i (c^+_ic_{i+1} + h.c.)$

The Jordan Wigner transformation acts as:

$c^+_i = Z_0\otimes..\otimes Z_{i-1} \otimes \sigma^+\otimes I_{i+1} \otimes I_{i+2}...$

and

$c_i = Z_0\otimes..\otimes Z_{i-1} \otimes \sigma^-\otimes I_{i+1} \otimes I_{i+2}...$

So we have, for example:
$ c^+_0 c_1 = Z_0\sigma^+_0\otimes\sigma^-_1\otimes I_2...$,

or

$ c^+_0 c_2 = Z_0\sigma^+_0\otimes Z_1\otimes \sigma^-_2\otimes I_3...$

Assume the ordering of particles is: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...,N$

Now, what happens if we swap two particles, say $0, 2, 1, 3, 4,...,N$ (we exchanged $2$ and $1$)..
How does the transformation look like now?
Do we have:
$ c^+_0 c_2 = Z_0\sigma^+_0\otimes\sigma^-_2\otimes I_1...$ ? or rather $ c^+_0 c_2 = Z_0\sigma^+_0\otimes Z_1 \otimes\sigma^-_2\otimes I_3...$

Comment: what do you mean you swap two particles? Jordan-Wigner transforms spin operators for an $S=1/2$ chain to fermionic operators.

Comment: reverse Jordan wigner transforms fermions to spins, we go from fermionic operators to Spin operators, and if you look at the Hamiltonian (chain of fermions) you can see clearly that the sites are ordered: i=0, 1, 2,..., N so the question is: what happens if you choose a different ordering e.g. i = 0, 2, 1, ..., N

Comment: The original Jordan-Wigner transform doesn't know the spatial ordering of the sites. You can relabel the sites however you want. The question is, is there any point in doing this? Typically you need to order the sites as they are spatially arranged so that local observables have expressions whose non-local strings cancel.

Comment: what about a jordan wigner transformation in two dimensions? doesn't the labeling of sites matter?

Comment: Again, there's not much point doing this in 2D but you can if you really try. The transform itself doesn't know anything about space, so you can just tabel the $L^2$ sites $\{(i,j)\}_{i,j=1}^{i,j=L}$ by $m=(i-1)L+j, m=1,\dots,L^2$. You will then find that the Jordan wigner transformed Hamiltonian will typically contain non-local terms with supports of size $\sim L$, which means the whole exercise is in futility.